# Чем отличаются виды или типы языков друг от друга?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Можно кратко, доходчиво, желательно на примере, разъяснить, чем отличаются эти виды или типы языков друг от друга? Пытался разобраться самостоятельно, но не могу отделаться от ощущения, что статьи противоречат друг другу.

Аналитические языки
Изолирующие языки
Синтетические языки
Флективные языки
Агглютинативные языки
Полисинтетические языки
Олигосинтетические языки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем вам вики не подходит? Если и там слишком сложно, то я тоже в затруднении.
Понимаете, "на пальцах" объяснять все это - непомерный труд...
Тем более, что о морфологической классификации (особенно применительно к синтетическим и производным от них) языков пока еще ведутся споры в отношении как квалифицирующих признаков, так и систематики в целом...

Но если в основном...

Вот классическая четырехтипная систематика на основе морфологии:

На основании **морфологического аспекта** выделяют несколько типов.

**Корневые языки**:
- изолирующие, для которых характерно полное отсутствие словоизменения и наличие грамматической значимости порядка слов, представленных только корнями. Непротивопоставление служебных слов и имён собственных, неразличение частей речи.
- основоизолирующие отличаются от изолирующих более развитой глагольной морфологией.

**Агглютинативные языки**:
Характеризуются развитой системой употребления суффиксов, приставок, добавляемых к неизменяемой основе слова, которые используются для выражения числа, падежа, рода и др. Включение служебных частиц (до 12) в состав слова – т.н. явления полисинтетизма и инкорпорации. Чёткое разграничение частей речи. Неиспользование окончаний.

**Флективные языки**:
Флективная морфология характерна, в основном, для большинства индоевропейских языков, а именно, для многих славянских, балтийских, албанского, греческого, санскрита, немецкого и исландского (английский и скандинавские относятся к смешанному типу, имеющему черты основоизолирующих и агглютинативных языков; романские, голландский, армянский, болгарский, македонский и индоиранские языки – профлективные). Характерно развитое употребление окончаний (флексий) для выражения рода, числа, падежа, сложная система склонения глаголов, чередование гласных в корне. Строгое различение частей речи. Порядок слов не всегда имеет значение.

**Профлективные (агглютинативно-флективные)**:
Промежуточное звено между агглютинативными и флективными языками. Для именного словоизменения характерна агглютинация, а для глагольного – флексия и чередование гласных (аблаут).

http://www.randevu-zip.narod.ru/caucase/type.htm
Мне кажется, тут все достаточно прозрачно.
Раньше профлективные языки специально типологически не выделяли, но зато как отдельный тип рассматривали **инкорпорирующие** или **полисинтетические** языки - о них ниже. 
Впоследствии пришло понимание, что понятие полисинтетизма - из другой типологии, синтаксической.

"Синтаксического" типа тут нет, "Синтетические" языки - это уже термин из другой классификации. Назовем её **"синтаксической" или "морфо-синтаксической"**.  Вот с ней действительно возникают сложности.

В ней синтаксические языки противопоставляются аналитическим и полисинтетическим.
Строго говоря под эту классификацию подпадают только флективные (по морфологической типологии) и частично - агглютинативные языки. Иногда это путает.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

Суть в том, что в **синтетических** языках, как это следует из названия, преобладают синтетические формы - один (некорневой) морф служит для выражения сразу нескольких синтаксических и семантических функций - как, например, в русском один глагольный суффикс отвечает за несколько категорий - залога, вида, времени и т.д. Аналогично - с флексиями существительных. Вот языки, где такая ситуация наблюдается как основное правило, и называют синтетическими.

В **аналитических** языках за образование новых форм отвечает отдельный морф или, чаще, дополнительное слово (сравните аналитическую форму будущего времени в русском: "будет писать" - "будет" здесь вспомогательный глагол, отвечает только за время, лицо и число, которых лишен смысловой глагол).

В **полисинтетических** языках отдельные отвечающие за синтаксис морфы "нанизываются" друг на друга  - в русском таким свойством обладают только некоторые глагольные суффиксы: 
*Писать - записать - запис**ыв**ать*. Языки, для которых такая схема словообразования является единственно возможной (или абсолютно преимущественной), относят к **полисинтетическим** (или условно-синтетическим) языкам. 
Беда в том, что таких, типологически однородных, языков почти нет, поэтому часто возникают недоразумения: к полисинтетическим языкам "для массовости" неправомерно относят языки с недостаточно выраженной степенью полисинтетичности.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

**Олигосинтетический язык** - это вообще очень спорный с точки зрения типологии термин, поскольку в природе такие языки не встречаются. 
Под таким языком понимают крайний случай синтетического языка - с небольшим числом некорневых морфем - атомов, из которых конструируется все необходимые синтаксические формы (а аналитические отсутствуют).

Некоторые из языков индейцев алгонкинской группы некоторое время считались олигосинтетическими (известный пример - язык блэкфут) - и это стало доводом в пользу использования такого типологического термина. Однако по мере изучения самих языков эту гипотезу отвергли.

Как крайний случай олигосинтетического языка иногда рассматривается "атомарный язык" - некая идеальная система, в который каждый морф имеет только одно значение, одну синтаксическую и семантическую роль и выражается одной фонемой. 
Естественно, что такой язык рассматривается только как некая идеализация, наподобие "абсолютно черного тела" в физике,  или "абсолютный растворитель" в химии (простите за примеры-аналогии из естественных наук, других что-то не приходит в голову).

(+)  
Кстати, есть еще одна грамматическая, куда более интересная типология языков - собственно **синтаксическая**. 
В ней выделяют, например, языки номинативные и эргативные.
Но эту тему я вынужденно опускаю, она совершенно неподъемна. Да и "не по формату" она тут. Мы все-таки о языке русском, а это сугубо теоретическая общая лингвистика, куда без соответствующей подготовки и соваться-то не стоит...
Кое-что про неё есть по первой ссылке в этом ответе.